# Databinding and service call in angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new in angular js last time i faced a problem so i sort out that was only binding text boxes data with each other so i did it in the following way

```
<div class="inner" ng-app="" ng-init="lastName , firstName , Tel , Email , dept , destination =''">
    <input type="text" id="Text1" ng-model="firstName" value='{{ firstName }}' onkeypress="return ignoreNumeric(event);">
    <label>Last Name *</label>
    <input type="text" id="Text2" ng-model="lastName" value='{{ lastName}}' onkeypress="return ignoreNumeric(event);">
    <label>First Name *</label>
    <input type="text" id="Text5" ng-model="firstName" value='{{ firstName }}' onkeypress="return ignoreNumeric(event);">
</div>
<div class="left_w1_fom3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
    <label>Last Name *</label>
    <input type="text" id="Text6" ng-model="lastName" value='{{ lastName}}' onkeypress="return ignoreNumeric(event);">
</div>
```

and so on long as required binding between text boxes but i am facing 3 problems now in binding and services so kindly help me to sort out?

1. If I load data into one name field dynamically on page load and make
   it read only It will automatically populated in other name fields
   but I want that field to be static if i change the data on others
   have no effect on that first field? how to
2. How to call an angular js service to fill address field when i finish completely filling zip , street , city name ?
3. What is 2 way binding in angular js and what is bulk copy?

Comment: @Khalil 2 way binding is basically something like this http://jsfiddle.net/HEdJF/ it is good example.

Comment: good but in my code i added only anglar js files and did not coded js like that its was still working as this updated http://jsfiddle.net/HEdJF/1637/

Comment: both doing same job check the latest updated fiddle and tell me difference so i get rid of 3 point 50$ remaining will be bulk copy

Comment: is this something u are looking for https://plnkr.co/edit/pOZWnZ1KQ4VY2CzBohAy?p=preview

Comment: yes but it is not working when i fill all feilds it automatically shows the filled data in another text box , why it is not working

Comment: ok also when user after entering values again change the value of feilds it start event

Comment: there is no validation for name here ...

Comment: Sorry ur query not clear! Are you refering to the code i did? And saying if the user changes the value of the zip again, the value of the address also changes?

Comment: i have done it thankyou

Comment: NO! So we have done point 2 and done point 3 =50% come to point 1 and bulk copy of 3

Comment: How about putting that value in a label or text. which is not changable through input. If you still persists to use input, then make the input `readonly`!

Comment: I HAVE MARKED INPUT READONLY BUT ON FIRST PAGE LOAD data automatically loaded to all feilds as they are binded with each other so change in other also change the data in first feild that is market as read only .. as user is not changing but code as they are binded

Comment: suppose data on load i loaded in firstname text feild it automatically angular js automatically fills all feilds where it is binded but as it is readonly so change in other name feilds that are binded with it wont cause change in firstname text feild a kind on ONE WAY BINDING that is not provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

incase smit plnkr link lost then same is this

```
  <body ng-app="changeExample">
<script>
 angular.module('changeExample', [])
 .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.change = function() {
    if($scope.user.zip == 123456)
    {
      $scope.user.address = "123 @ SV USA"
    }
   };
   }]);
 </script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
 <div class="inner" ng-app="" ng-init="lastName , firstName , Tel , Email  
   ,    dept , destination =''">
 <label>Name *</label>
   <input type="text" id="Text1" ng-model="user.name"  onkeypress="return  
  ignoreNumeric(event);">
  <label>ZIP *</label>
  <input type="text" id="Text2" ng-model="user.zip" ng-change="change()"  
 onkeypress="return ignoreNumeric(event);">
 <label>Address *</label>
 <input type="text" id="Text5" ng-model="user.address"  onkeypress="return  
 ignoreNumeric(event);">
</div>
```